# Do I need to initialize a public List variable in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to create a list of horses and print the name of the Horses that are stored in the list. Although I got the answer correct as I desired, there's one thing that is puzzling me when I declare a list variable.

I declared it as:

`public List<string> myFavouriteHorses;`

and in an example I have seen it's declared like this:

`public List<string> myFavouriteHorses = new List<string> ();`

Despite this difference, both of them worked. What's the difference between these two approaches? Does it matter which one I use?

Here's the entire code which i tried:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LearningScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<string> myFavouriteHorses = new List<string> ();

    void Start(){
        myHorses ();
        }

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return)) {
            Print ();

        }

    }

    void myHorses(){

        myFavouriteHorses.Add ("Grey Horse");
        myFavouriteHorses.Add ("Black Horse");
        myFavouriteHorses.Add ("Rudolph Horse");
        myFavouriteHorses.Add ("Biting Horse");
    }

    void Print(){
        Debug.Log ("This list has " + myFavouriteHorses.Count + " horses");

        Debug.Log ("The horse at index 1 is " + myFavouriteHorses [1]);
        Debug.Log ("The horse at index 2 is " + myFavouriteHorses [2]);
        Debug.Log ("The horse at index 3 is" + myFavouriteHorses [3]);

    }

}
```

Here's the output

[image: Output]

Why doesn't it make a difference whether or not I initialize the `List` with `new` before using it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: public List<string> myFavouriteHorses = new List<string> (); VS  public List<string> myFavouriteHorses;

Comment: This is not a game development related question.  Voting to close.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why do we use  '  = new List <string>  ' ?

Comment: @ThePercept Because you are initialising the list, otherwise `myFavouriteHorses` would be `NULL`

Comment: list is part of the system library. this is a generic programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Unity's editor automatically creates the  `new List ()` part when generating the game. That's how you can already populate it with data in the editor. Things assigned in the editor will be added to the gameobject even BEFORE `Awake()` and `Start()` so if you assign the variable somewhere in `Awake()` or `Start()` (or in a function called during one of them, such as `myHorses()`) it will override the assignment done in the editor.

Comment: What? No. You are populating the list in `myHorses ();`. You call  `myHorses ();` in  `start ();`, so when you come to access members of the list `myFavouriteHorses` it already has all the elements in it.

Comment: Oops. I should edit that to be more clear.

Comment: Are you sure inspector properties are assigned after Awake()? I could have sworn I've read this information in Awake without issues...

Comment: I'm actually not 100% certain, but if there's a place it would happen, it would be there. I'll go double-check.

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong. Just tested it, and the inspector variable was already changed by the time Awake was called. Editing now.